# How to handle iOS status bar height change during active call in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When on a call the status bar in iOS changes height. The larger status bar causes the TabBarIOS in my RN iOS app to be partly pushed off the bottom of the screen. Additionally, when switching tabs, the new tab displayed is first displayed with the middle missing, as if the top half of the screen is offset down for the larger status bar, but the bottom half isn't, and the discrepancy is handled by an overlap in the center. Is anyone else seeing this, and if so, have a solution?

Comment: have you found any solution? It seems it was possible to listen for height change in former RN versions but not anymore

Answer (score 0):

Can You provide some code snippet to see what exactly is going in there ?
Additionally you can call the StatusBar to display the notification bar contents and Add a view of height 64pt that is Standard with ios10 design standards.